# editable php mysql table with csv import

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, csv

Currently I am developing this admin dashboard which allows me to add, delete, rename the columns of a database. I also have a csv import php script, which allows me to populate the database. But when I edit, add or remove a column from the table, obviously my csv import php script does not work.

Is there a way of writing this csv import php script in which it will import the data (assuming the fields are in correct place) without specifying the column names?

Comment: what about grabbing the column names first and then build the query with that?

Comment: that would make sense, but to read the "lines" in the csv dynamically? without knowing how many are there

Comment: if you want a completly "anything goes" kind of import, you need to do the logic of "if i get only 3 columns, fill those into x, y, z. if you have between n and n+5, fill those into blabablalbla", otherwise the csv should contain the same number of rows as your database. then iterate over the lines with any kind of array or object loop

Comment: great @LordNeo thanks!